# OpenSUSE: why does "service ... start" always stop my application?

Tags: opensuse

I am running OpenSUSE LEAP 15. I am trying to define an application as service such that I can start/stop it using `service <servicename> start` or `service <servicename> stop`, resp. and also to restart it automatically on a system restart.

But for some odd reason this doesn't work! My application never runs after a `service <servicename> start` :-(

The `<servicename>.service` file that I defined in `/usr/lib/systemd/system` contains the two commands:

```
...
ExecStart=/opt/zhquest/current/ctlscript.sh start
ExecStop=/opt/zhquest/current/ctlscript.sh stop
...
```

When I call the script manually, i.e. when I enter `ctlscript.sh start` or `ctlscript.sh stop` then the application starts and stops fine as it should.

But - as I found out by adding `echo` statements to the script - when I issue a `service <servicename> start` then the script is actually called twice, first with the argument `start` and then again with the argument `stop`. Naturally the application then does not run, since it gets stopped again immediately after it got started.

Why is that so??? Why does the `service` command call my `ctlscript.sh` twice, first with argument `start` and then again with argument `stop` when I enter `service <servicename> start`? That seems completely absurd!

Answer (score 0):

Just for the benefit of anyone stumbling over this thread:

I found the answer for my problem here: https://superuser.com/questions/1022142/why-is-systemd-stopping-service-immediately-after-it-is-started

In short: If the application being called to start the application is actually a control script which itself terminates after having done its job of starting (i.e. forking) the application (as is the case here - `ctlscript.sh` is exactly such a script) then the service type needs to be of `Type=forking` (and not `Type=simple` as I had specified since I had simply copied the service-file from another .service-file and only replaced the `ExecStart=...` and `ExecStop=...`-values.

Since the started script ends `systemd` "thinks" that the started application has crashed and immediately executes a subsequent stop-command with the intention to clean up after a crashed applicaiton start.

Here, however, it's normal that the script terminates after having done its job and that is signaled with the `...=forking`-option.